# Jquery - how to play .animate() once and reset it with other button

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am making a website with some divs that slide into the screen.
How can I make the div that is already in the front NOT play the animation when the respective button is pressed?

I set up the jQuery for each div like this:

```
$(button).click(function(event) {
  $(div).css("right", "-100%");
  $(div).animate({right: '0%'});
  $(div).css("z-index", "1");
  $(other-div).css("z-index", "0");
});
```

I need to make the 'hidden' div's play the animation to make them come to the front. I just don't want the animation to play if the div is already in the front.

Here's a fiddle of what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/cn6goeuq/

I have tried to use .delay() like this:

```
$(button).click(function(event) {
  $(div).animate({right: '0%'});
  $(div).css("z-index", "1");
  $(other-div).css("z-index", "0");
  $(other-div).delay(2000).css("right", "-100");
});
```

so that the hidden div would go back to 'right: -100%' unnoticed, but it didn't work. No idea why.

I also tried to use a variable to help me activate and deactivate the animation of the div that is showing but also in vain. I wanted something like this:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

  $(button1).click(function(event1){
      $(div1).animate({right: '0%'});
    x++;
    y=0;
    if (x >= 1) {
      $(this).off(event1);
  }
  });

  $(button2).click(function(event2){
      $(div2).animate({right: '0%'});
    y++;
    x=0;
    if (y >= 1) {
      $(this).off(event2);
    }
  });
```

I wanted to make the event1 work only once when button1 is pressed and reset if other button is pressed but it also didn't work.

I ran out of ideas of how to solve this!

EDIT

I'm afraid that making the animation conditional did not work as well. I had exactly the same result. I tried making it conditional according to the z-index. Like this:

```
$(button).click(function(event) { 
  if($(div).css('z-index') !== '0'){ 
    $(div).css("right", "-100%");
    $(div).animate({right: '0%'});
  };
  $(div).css("z-index", "1");
  $(other-div).css("z-index", "0");
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just make the animation conditional of whether it already has a css attribute that is equal to `right: 0%` such as this:

```
$(button).click(function(event) {
  if($(div).css('right') != '0px'){
     $(div).css("right", "-100%");
     $(div).animate({right: '0%'});

  };
});
```

Edit: 

The initial if-statement was faulty as jQuery `.css` returns the value with the suffix "px", and it previously was attempted to match with "0%".

Here's an updated fiddle solving the if-statement issue and allowing to switch between elements applying different z-index: https://jsfiddle.net/cn6goeuq/3/

Comment: I'm afraid that making the animation conditional did not work. I had exactly the same result. I also tried making it conditional according to the z-index. Like this:

    $(button).click(function(event) {
           if($(div).css('z-index') !== '0'){
           $(div).css("right", "-100%");
           $(div).animate({right: '0%'});};
           $(div).css("z-index", "1");
           $(other-div).css("z-index", "0");
});

Comment: @Chris.s Yes, it worked perfectly. It turns out I was using it wrong somehow. I just used z-index as the conditional because it is more consistent throughout the divs in the website itself. I used the code I posted in the question in my last edit but with a slight change.

Comment: @JoseSoares actually it turns out that my if-statement didnt work either, as the css returns the value as "0px", meaning that =! '0%' was wrong. I have updated this fiddle to tale care of it, and only switching between z-index (so you can switch between the divs): https://jsfiddle.net/cn6goeuq/3/

Answer (score 1):

In my last edit I made a mistake. The answer was simple:

```
$(button).click(function(event) { 
  if($(div).css('z-index') !== '1'){ 
    $(div).css("right", "-100%");
    $(div).animate({right: '0%'});
  };
  $(div).css("z-index", "1");
  $(other-div).css("z-index", "0");
});


$(other-button).click(function(event) { 
  if($(other-div).css('z-index') !== '1'){ 
    $(other-div).css("right", "-100%");
    $(other-div).animate({right: '0%'});
  };
  $(other-div).css("z-index", "1");
  $(div).css("z-index", "0");
});
```

From what I understood it basically says 'if the div's z-index is not 1 it plays the animation' which was exactly what I was looking for.

@Chris gave the answer but I am reposting it for clarification for future references

Answer (score 0):

If you want an event only works for one time use **one** that works like **on** but only for one time:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 function animateRed(){
    $("#redDiv").animate({
      right: '0%'
    });
    $("#redDiv").css("z-index", "1");
    $("#yellowDiv").css("z-index", "0");
 }
 
 function animateYellow(){
  $("#yellowDiv").css("right", "-100%");
    $("#redDiv").delay(1000).css("right", "-100%");
    $("#yellowDiv").animate({right: '0%' });
    $("#yellowDiv").css("z-index", "1");
    $("#redDiv").css("z-index", "0");
 }

  $("#redButton").one('click', function() {
     animateRed()
  });

  $("#yellowButton").one('click', function() {
    animateYellow();    
  });
  
  $("#yellowButton").click(function(){
     $("#redButton").one('click', function() {
     animateRed()
     });
  })
  
  $("#redButton").click(function(){
     $("#yellowButton").one('click', function() {
     animateYellow()
     });
  })

  $("#back").click(function(event) {
    $("#yellowDiv").animate({
      right: '-100%'
    });
    $("#redDiv").animate({
      right: '-100%'
    });
    $("#yellowDiv").css("z-index", "0");
    $("#redDiv").css("z-index", "0");
    $("#yellowButton").one('click', function() {
     animateYellow()
     });
     $("#redButton").one('click', function() {
     animateRed()
     });
    
  });

});
```

```css
#redDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  right: -100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}

#yellowDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  right: -100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="redButton">RED</div>
  <div id="yellowButton">YELLOW</div>
  <div id="back">BOTH BACK</div>
  <div id="redDiv"></div>
  <div id="yellowDiv"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I also thought about that option, but I need to be able to play it as many times as I want. I only DON'T want to play the animation when the div is 'in the front'.

Comment: If you can see the fiddle I posted, when you press RED it plays the animation and you can see the red div. But if you press RED again it plays the animation again but without needing to. I hope that makes any sense